# Can I give credit for answering question by posting answer and writing their username in the answer

Tags: feature-request, comments, questions, answers

Someone answered my question within a comment how can I give them credit?

I went ahead and posted his answer,  gave him credit it in the answer and selected it an the asnwer. is this considered sloppy?

Comment: Slightly different - as there's nothing here indicating that someone other than the commenter or OP posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I normally comment on the comment (which you can do on your own questions before you get the site-wide comment [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)) stating that this has solved my problem and prompting the user to post it as an answer.

After a period of time, if they haven't added an answer, and no-one else has provided a more detailed answer, I would post it as the answer, calling out the comment and accepting it (when able - you have to wait before you can accept your own answers).

We could almost do with a "Make this comment an answer" type mod tool as well as the "Make this answer a comment".